# How to find a closest point on a constraint to a given point?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors, solution-verification, constraints

(This is a multi-variable calculus problem, not a linear algebra one)

Find the closest point to the point $(2,7,8)$ on the constraint:

$$ 4x + 7y = x+3y+5z$$

And find the projection of the vector $(2,7,8)$ on the plane:

$$3x+4y =5z$$

My try:

I thought to use Lagrange multipliers, but then switched to just finding the line perpendicular to the plane (Which I am not sure if is a legal move) :

$g(x,y,z) = 3x + 4y - 5z = 0$

The vector perpendicular to the plane is $\vec{n} = (3,4,-5)$

and so the line that is perpendicular to the plane, and goes through the point is: $(2,7,8) + t(3,4,-5) = (2+3t, 7+4t, 8-5t)$

And if we look where it intersects the plane (then it has to satisfy the plane's equation):

$ 3(2+3t) + 4(7+4t) -5(8-5t) = 0 \Rightarrow 50t = 6 \Rightarrow t = \frac{3}{25}$

And thus the closest point is: $(2 + \frac{9}{25}, 7+\frac{12}{25}, 8-\frac{30}{25}) = ( 2.36, 7.48, 7.4)$

For the projection, I need to find $P_w( \vec{(2,7,8)} ) $ and the projection will be: $\vec{(2,7,8)} - P_w( \vec{2,7,8})$ But couldn't find $P_w$ I thought it is just $xy$ component $(2,7,0)$ and then we negate the vector $(-2,-7,-8)$ and add them to get: $(0,0, -8)$

Comment: Isn't the closest point and the projection the same here?

Comment: @Jan But the projection is a vector and a point is a point - no? so how can they be the same?

Comment: no a point is a vector. @Jan is right

Comment: But I am confused, this is not the same plane as before, I think of it as another "question" even though they might be related (I am even not sure if my closest point is right ) @crush3dice

Comment: It is the same one. Substract $x$ and $3y$

Comment: @crush3dice Oh you are right, I missed that one, but - how do I get the projection? I mean, is it a sentence that the projection is the closest point?

Comment: one can proof that, yes. Intuitivly it works like this. For every point $x$ in your plane take the vector $v = p -x$, where $p$ is your point. Then divide $v$ into its component inside the plane and inside the orthogonal complement of your plane. Then you get that the length of $v$ is minimal if the component inside the plane is $0$ (by pythagoras). Thats exactly what the projection would do to $p$

Comment: @crush3dice Is there a more systematic way of finding the projection? I don't think we are allowed to make a statement and then prove its correctness .. Thanks!

Comment: You could construct the projection by finding two normalized vectors whose span is your plane. Then take the scalar product of your point with both of them and sum the results. Then thats the component of $p$ inside the plane. Or differently said. Its $p$ without its orthogonal amount.

Comment: @crush3dice I know how to take the 2 vectors that span my plane but I am not sure if it is a "calculus move" - I mean, this is an MVC course and not a linear algebra (which I've done 1 year ago..) so I don't think it is legal.. :\

Comment: Can you assume that $\langle v, w\rangle = \|v\|\|w\| cos(\varphi)$ where $\varphi$ is the angle between $v$ and $w$ ? Or can you use pythagoras?

Comment: Find the projection of a vector is entirely a linerar algebra sort of question.  But, if you feel the need to use an approach grounded in calculus, Lagrange multipliers is fine.  And, Lagrange multipliers should quickly give you the very equations that you have used.  The maneuver that you have used is "legal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the closest point is correct.

Concerning the second question: If $u$ is a vector and $v$ is a second vector (both non-zero), then the projection $\operatorname{proj}_v u$ of $u$ onto $v$ is given by

$$\operatorname{proj}_v u = \frac{\langle u, v\rangle}{\|v\|^2} v.$$

Now, a moment's thought reveals that the projection of $u$ onto a plane $E$ with normal vector $n$ is given by

$$\operatorname{proj}_E u = u - \operatorname{proj}_n u.$$

(To imagine this, think of the plane to be horizontal. Then calculating the projection means computing $u$ minus the vertical component of $u$. What remains then is the horizontal component. The vertical component is exactly given by the projection of $u$ onto $n$.)

Plugging in the given values with $u = (2, 7, 8)^\intercal$ and $n = (3, 4, -5)^\intercal$ finally shows that the results are indeed the same:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 7 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{-6}{50} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ -5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 + 18/50 \\ 7 + 24/50 \\ 8 - 30/50 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: This is somewhat of a linear algebra approach, is there a more "calculus"-ly solution? this answer helps me a lot thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, then you just should use Lagrange multipliers (since the projection is the closest point), as suggested in your approach.